# Constructor cannot be redeclared

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm practicing constructor overloads. I've learnt that constructor can be overloaded few times but when I try it says "Constructor cannot be redeclared". What can be the problem? If I delete one of constructors it runs. Should I add destructor or what should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Cat
{
private:
    string name;
    string breed;
    int age;
    int weight;

public:
    Cat(string newName, string newBreed, int newAge, int newWeight)
    {
        name = newName;
        breed = newBreed;
        age = newAge;
        weight = newWeight;
    }

    Cat(string nName, string nBreed, int nAge, int nWeight)
    {
        name = nName;
        breed = nBreed;
        age = nAge;
        weight = nWeight;
    }

    string toString()
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "Name - ";
        ss << name << endl;
        ss << "Breed - ";
        ss << breed << endl;
        ss << "Age - ";
        ss << age << endl;
        ss << "Weight - ";
        ss << weight << endl;

        cout << ss.str() << endl;

        return ss.str();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cat a("Illidan", "Maine-Coon", 2, 12);
    a.toString();

    Cat b("Sammy", "Turkish Angora", 2, 8);
    b.toString();
}
```

Comment: The name of the parameters doesn't matter.  Both of your constructors have the signature `Cat(string, string, int, int)`.  You can't do that.

Comment: They can be _overloaded_, which means you can have multiple constructors with different signatures. Yours have the same signature.

Comment: Oh I see now. thank you :)

Comment: Well, ask yourself what you expected the duplicate constructor to provide that the first one didn't.  If it's different names, then you would need to write thousands of constructors, if not millions of them, just because the name of the parameters changed.  And you know that couldn't make sense, right?